# Android. getHistorySize and getHistoricalX/Y

Tags: android, exception

I have overridden the `onTouchEvent()` method in my `View` class, and tried to handle an `EventMotion.ACTION_MOVE`.

I use the following code :

```
if (event_.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {  
    historySize = event_.getHistorySize();  
    endX = event_.getHistoricalX(historySize-1);  
}
```

I don't want to discuss the safety of this code.

On Android 2.1-update1 and Android 2.2.1 it works perfectly, but on Android 2.3.1 it crashes with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception.

What changed in `getHistorySize()` and `getHistoricalX()` in Android 2.3.1 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just come across the same issue. It would appear that after 2.3.x getHistoricalX() and getHistoricalY() now throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds when passed a negative figure. Previously they just returned the first entry in the history. This would happen where historySize is 0, from a very short press,

Thus, although you do not want to discuss code safety, the answer is a check on the historySize as follows. If historySize==0, although a Move event, it hasn't actually moved so presumably you don't want to do anything.

```
if (event_.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
historySize = event_.getHistorySize();
if(historySize>0)
endX = event_.getHistoricalX(historySize-1);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I use checking like this.