# why is Android MotionEvent.getHistoricalX is thowing an exception

Tags: android, exception, motionevent

I am using a `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` in order to implement pinch-to-zoom in Android. I am extending a `TextView` class and therefore the method `setTextSize()` is already implemented. The following is my code for `onScroll()`.

```
 @Override
 public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
     if(LOGGING) Log.v(MODULE_NAME, "onScroll()");

     float x, y;
     float oldDist, newDist;

     if (e2.getPointerCount() == 2 && 
         ((e2.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)) {
         x = e2.getHistoricalX(0, 0) - e2.getHistoricalX(1, 0);
         y = e2.getHistoricalY(0, 0) - e2.getHistoricalY(1, 0);
         oldDist = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
         if (oldDist > 10) {
             if (LOGGING) Log.d(MODULE_NAME, "Starting ZOOM mode");                    
             x = e2.getX(0) - e2.getX(1);
             y = e2.getY(0) - e2.getY(1);
             newDist = FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);

             if (newDist > 30) {
                    float scaleFactor = (newDist > oldDist) ? oldDist : newDist;
                    float scale = (newDist - oldDist) / scaleFactor;
                    // Callback to be processed in main thread
                    setTextSize(scale * currentTextSize);
                    oldDist = newDist;
             }      
             scrollDetected = true;
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;            
 }
```

My problem is that occasionally, **not always**, `getHistoricalX()` throws an exception. I am attaching the LogCat result.

```
07-31 16:53:30.358: V/ZoomTextView(19540): onScroll()
07-31 16:53:30.358: E/InputEventReceiver(19540): Exception dispatching input event.
07-31 16:53:30.358: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19540): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-31 16:53:30.358: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19540): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: historyPos out of range
07-31 16:53:30.358: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19540):  at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetAxisValue(Native Method)
07-31 16:53:30.358: E/MessageQueue-JNI(19540):  at android.view.MotionEvent.getHistoricalX(MotionEvent.java:2739)
```

Since I know that there are 2 pointers and that the history is at least the size of 0, It is not clear to me how or why this exception occurs. Can anyone please assist?

I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674293/android-gethistorysize-and-gethistoricalx-y), and it was of no help to me.

Comment: How do you know there is a history? You're not checking `getHistorySize()` at all. If it's size 0, then index 0 is not valid(that would be size 1).

Comment: I thought that if there is no history, index 0 would be the current one

Comment: No, that's just `getX`, not `getHistoricalX`

Comment: I'd be happy to accept your answer, if you posted it as such. It solved my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before using `getHistoricalX()` or `getHistoricalY()`, you should check the size with `getHistorySize()`.

If it returns zero, you know there are no historical events. Then you just have to process the current events, using `getX()` and `getY()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have the same problem and it was resolved thanks to Geobits answer. Just check `getHistorySize()` is not returning 0:

```
            if (event.getHistorySize() > 0) {

                float lastX = event.getHistoricalX(0);

            }
```